# Get Conditional Formatting Data (color) from another Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In sheet 1 I have a conditional rule that displays the cell as red if it has data or green if it is empty.

In sheet 2, I use the formula `=Sheet1!A1` to retrieve the data from sheet 1 in the corresponding sheet 2 cells. However, I only want to retrieve the cell colour not the data value.

How can I retrieve the colour from the cell, and not the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that Google Apps Script is required to be used. So, for example, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script.

```
const GETCOLOR = range => SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(range).getBackgrounds();

function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1") return;
  const f = "=GETCOLOR";
  const t = "=sample";
  [[f, t], [t, f]].forEach(([a, b]) => e.source.createTextFinder(`^\\${a}`).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(b));
}
```

- When you use this script, please put a formula of `=GETCOLOR("Sheet1!A1")` and `=GETCOLOR("Sheet1!A1:B10")` as a custom function. By this, the background color is returned as the HEX value.
- About the added function `onEdit`, from `In sheet 1 I have a conditional rule that displays the cell as red if it has data or green if it is empty.`, in this case, I thought that when a cell is edited and the background color is changed, you might want to update the custom function of `GETCOLOR`. In order to achieve this, I used `onEdit`. When the cells of "Sheet1" are edited, the custom function of `GETCOLOR` is updated.

#### Note:

- If you want to copy and paste the background color from the source range to the destination range, how about the following sample script? When you run this script with the script editor, the background color is copied.

  ```
    function sample() {
      const srcRange = "Sheet1!A1"; // Please set the source range as the A1Notation.
      const dstRange = "Sheet2!A1"; // Please set the destination range as the A1Notation.
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const bk = ss.getRange(srcRange).getBackgrounds();
      ss.getRange(dstRange).offset(0, 0, bk.length, bk[0].length).setBackgrounds(bk);
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Script 1 works. It is not a perfect solution, as I still need to run the script after every change. If I can't find my original solution I will accept this answer. Thanks

Comment: @P.Sav Thank you for replying. About `as I still need to run the script after every change.`, in this case, when you changed the background colors of the cells on "Sheet1", you want to update the formula. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @P.Sav Thank you for replying. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.